# ga.js to analytics.js - Event Function Checking for _gaq

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm migrating our system from ga.js to analytics.js and I have a function that submits an event. The function is:

```
function _fireGoogleEvent() {
    if (_gaq) {
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EventCategory', 'Submitted']);

        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'EventCatergory', 'Submitted']);
    }
}
```

When migrating to analtyics.js, will I need to check if ga exists like they are checking to see if _gaq exists? I know ga.js checks to see if it exists in the normal snippet with `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` but they didn't try to set it as an array here even if it didn't exist so I can't really think of a reason why else they'd be checking for it. There isn't any other points in the code where they submit another event either, so the only other thing they could be checking for would be if the tracker exists when the created a page view. I can't really see any reason for them to be checking for _gaq, unless they were semi trying to replicate the var `_gaq = _gaq || [];`, or is this just attempting to see if the tracker already exists, and if so, send this event? I don't believe it's the later though, because I don't see any attempt to create a tracker otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace `_gaq` with `ga` in this condition and adapt the tracking lines.

When you do:

```
_gaq = _gaq || []
```

you are creating an array to push these events to if it doesn't already exist. If analytics is added to the page after this code has already run,.(i.e. by an asynchronous script) then it will find and push these tracking events after it loads.

When you do:

```
if (_gaq)
```

you are simply not doing the task if _gaq is not present. This also prevents the code from having an exception when an analytics snippet is unexpectedly missing, but wont store these events in case an analytics snippet is added to the page after this code has already run.